# Use function within a function

Tags: racket

I have a function called `clean-up` which basically does what the already available `flatten` function does. I then have a function called `multiplier`, which takes in a list and multiplies all the numbers within it. The one issue is that sometimes there could be a weird syntax for the list used in `multiplier`, and it doesn't multiply every number together. For example:

**Example Input**

```
(multiplier '((1 (2 3)) 4 5 (6)))
```

**Correct Output**

```
720
```

**My Output**

```
*: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: '(6 . 1)
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments...
```

We don't like errors now do we? This `multiplier` function works in a normal-looking list, something like `(multiplier '(1 2 3 4 5 6))`. So I wrote the `clean-up` function to turn some confusing-looking list into a normal-looking list. However, I don't know how to call it to clean-up my list before trying to parse through and do the multiplication. I can verify that the `clean-up` function does its job perfectly. Can anyone help? Here is the code I have for both:

```
(define (clean-up s)
  (cond [(null? s) '()]
        [(not (pair? s)) (list s)]
        [else (append (clean-up (car s)) (clean-up (cdr s)))]
))

(define multiplier
  (lambda (s)
    (cond [(null? s) 1]
          [(number? (car s)) (* (car s) (multiplier(cdr s)))]
          [list? (car s) (append (car s) (multiplier(cdr s)))]
          [else (multiplier (cdr s))]
)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the `clean-up` function to solve the problems encountered in `multiplier`. However, you could call `clean-up` on the input first simply with:

```
scratch.rkt> (multiplier (clean-up '((1 (2 3)) 4 5 (6))))
720
```

Or, you could create a helper function to do this for you:

```
(define (multiplier-workaround s)
  (multiplier (clean-up s)))
```

```
scratch.rkt> (multiplier-workaround '((1 (2 3)) 4 5 (6)))
720
```

A workaround like this might help you out in a pinch, but it does not fix the real problems in the code.

Some of the problems here may be easier to see with better code formatting. It is *bad* style to leave hanging parentheses in Lisps as if these are C-style languages; but that probably isn't causing you problems here. Yet it is *good* style to show the structure of your expressions using indentation. With proper indentation it becomes apparent that there are missing parentheses in the line with the `list?` predicate:

```
(define multiplier
  (lambda (s)
    (cond [(null? s) 1]
          [(number? (car s))
           (* (car s) (multiplier(cdr s)))]
          [list? (car s)
                 (append (car s) (multiplier (cdr s)))]
          [else
           (multiplier (cdr s))])))
```

Further investigation of that line shows that the code is attempting to append `(car s)` to the result of `(multiplier (cdr s))`; yet, `(car s)` is now known to be a list, and `multiplier` is supposed to return a number! The intention here was surely to *multiply* the result of calling `multiply` on the list `(car s)` together with the result of `(multiplier (cdr s))`:

```
(define multiplier
  (lambda (s)
    (cond [(null? s) 1]
          [(number? (car s))
           (* (car s)
              (multiplier (cdr s)))]
          [(list? (car s))
           (* (multiplier (car s))
              (multiplier (cdr s)))]
          [else
           (multiplier (cdr s))])))
```

It isn't clear why the `else` branch is needed, unless OP wants to be able to process lists such as `(a (1 (2 b) (3 (c (4 5) 6) d) e)))`. For code that is expecting nested lists of numbers, this would be fine:

```
(define multiplier-2
  (lambda (s)
    (cond [(null? s) 1]
          [(number? (car s))
           (* (car s) (multiplier (cdr s)))]
          [else
           (* (multiplier (car s))
              (multiplier (cdr s)))])))
```

Both functions now work for OP example expression, and the corrected OP code also works for input with spurious values:

```
scratch.rkt> (multiplier '((1 (2 3)) 4 5 (6)))
720
scratch.rkt> (multiplier-2 '((1 (2 3)) 4 5 (6)))
720
scratch.rkt> (multiplier '(a (1 (2 3)) 4 5 b (6) c))
720
```

Answer (score 0):

I think buildin `flatten` have more error handling.

```
(define (multiplier lst)
  (apply * (filter number? (flatten lst))))

;;; TEST
(define test-lst1 (list + (vector 1) '(1 (2 3) c) "w" 4 5 '(6) + - * sqr))
(define test-lst2 '(1(a 2(3 b (c 4(d 5 e(6) (f)))))))
(multiplier test-lst1) ; 720
(multiplier test-lst2) ; 720
```